# Store an image locally in React Server Side Rendering App

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a React Server Side Rendering App. There's a performance issue when images are to be displayed on the page. For an image to be displayed, there's a network call for the image from the server and then it's displayed on screen. For larger images, it takes a while to load the image which is very evident. Is there a way once the request is made to the server and the image is received as response to have the image stored locally and use the locally stored image when needed again without making a network request. I couldn't find any good resource to help me through this one, it would be of great help if you could help me with this one or even point me to a reference!

Comment: There are many ways you could go about trying to solve this issue

Comment: Could you please advise me with a way to solve this issue. I am new to UI development and I am confused as to how to go forward.

Comment: What you're describing is a cache. Cloudflare is the most prominent service here that offers this without you having to change your code. That's about as specific an answer as this question...